# No module error while trying to compress static files

Tags: python, node.js, less, uglifyjs

I'm trying to compress my static files using node and keep getting a no module error

```
Basil-MBP:syte Basil$ python compress.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compress.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf
```

Here is a link to my compress.py file:
https://github.com/bsiddiqui/bsiddiqui.com/blob/master/syte/compress.py

Comment: is django available on your python path? is your environment activiated?

Comment: Wow silly mistake - it wasn't available in my python path. Post your response as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is django available on your python path? is your environment activiated?